# Set search dialog text dynamically

Tags: android

Does anyone knows how to set the text of search dialog dynamically ? 
    I want to realize the effect that when the search key pressed, a specific text can be initialized in the search dialog. 
    Waiting for your suggestions. Thx~~

Comment: Which view you are using for this purpose ?

Answer (score 5):

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    startSearch("initial query", true, null, false);
    return false;
}
```